# How the flow of this context should be? ( Where to put the code to process the payment depending on the selected payment method?)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a multi-step form for a user to register in a conference, all steps are in the same `registration.blade.php` page, in step 1  and step 2 is done an ajax request to validate the form fields.

The steps are:

- Step1 is to collect some info about the user (*name and tin number*)
- Step 2 is to collect the payment method (*credit card or references*)
- Step 3 is the payment
- Step 4 shows a success message (*this step only appears after a successful payment with a credit card, with the references payment method this step don't appear, with references payment method only the step 1, 2 and 3 appears*)

My doubt is between the step 2 and 3.

If the selected payment method references is necessary to execute the code below, that generates some payment references and then present that references to the user in step 3. When the user pays the system receives a notification and should be inserted in the payments table the `price`, `payment_method_id`, `registration_id` and `status` (*paid*).

**Code to process payments with references:**

```
    public function ReferencesCharge(Request $request)
        {
           $payment_info = [
        'name' => "user name",
        'email' => 'user email',
        'value' => 'registration total price',
        'id' => 'registration id',
    ];

    $newPayment = new Payment($payment_info);
    $reference = $newPayment->gererateReferences();

    //$reference returns an array with necessary codes to present to the user so he can pay

    // after generate references is necessary:
            // show in step 3 the generated references
            // insert an entry in the payments table when the system receives a notification from 3rd party service informing that the user did the payment

}
```

If the selected payment was credit card is necessary to execute the code below to charge the credit card and after that is inserted in the payments table the `price`, `payment_method_id`, `registration_id` and `status` (*paid*). And then the user should be redirected to step 4 to show a success message:

**Code to process credit card payments:**

```
public function creditCardCharge(Request $request)
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
        $source = $request->stripeToken;

        try{
            Charge::create([
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'amount' => 2500,
                'source' => $source,
            ]);
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            return response()->json(['status' => $e->getMessage()], 422);
        }

        // after charging the card with success:
            // insert an entry in the payments table 
            // redirect to success confirmation step to inform the user that payment was done with success 
    }
```

My doubt is how the flow should be, where the code to handle the payment with references and the code to handle the payment with a credit card should be placed. So is possible to achieve this scenario:

[image]

For now, I just have the step 1 and step 2 working properly. To handle step1 and step2 I have the `RegistrationController`. In the step1 the info introduced by the user is validated using an ajax post request to the `storeUserInfo()` method of the `RegistrationController` if returns `200` the user goes to step2.

In the step2, the user selects the payment method and clicks in "go to step 3" is also done an ajax request to the `storePaymentMethods()` of the `RegistrationController` to validate if the user selected at least 1 payment method. My doubt is after this method return code 200 how the process should be.

Depending on the payment method, it necessary to run the appropriate code above (*code that generates payment references or code to charge credit card*).

So, my doubt how to organize this code in terms of controllers and methods, where to put that code that should execute depending on the selected payment method. Do you know how the flow should be to achieve that?

Maybe an approach can be something like below in `storePaymentMethods()` but it doesn't seem very correct do everything in this method:

```
public function storePaymentMethods(Request $request){
       $request->validate([
            'payment_method' => 'required',
        ]);

        if($request->payment_method == "references"){
          // generate codes and present to the user that codes
        }
        else if($request->payment_method == "credit_card"){
          // show credit card inputs to the user
          // and process the credit card payment with stripe
        }



        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success',
            'payment_method' => $request->payment_method,
        ], 200);
    }
```

---

**A full summary of the flow of the registration with the multistep form that I have for now:**

So for the step1, there is the form:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <!-- fields of the step 1-->
        <input type="submit" href="#step2" id="goToStep2" class="btn next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

step1 image to explain better:

[image]

when the user clicks in "Go to step 2" button is made an ajax request to validate the data and if there are no errors, code 200 is returned and the user go to the step 2:

```
$('#goToStep2').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id_step1);
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '{{ route('conferences.storeRegistrationInfo', compact('id','slug') ) }}',
        data: custom_form.serialize(),
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
            nextTab($active);
        },
        error: function (data) {    
            // show errors
        }
    });
});
```

Then in the ConferencesController there is teh storeRegistrationInfo() to handle the above ajax request:

```
public function storeRegistrationInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){  
    $rules = [];
    $messages = [];

    $rules["name_invoice"] = 'required|max:255|string';
    $rules["TIN_invoice"] = ['required', 'string', new ValidTIN()];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    $errors = $validator->errors();
    $errors =  json_decode($errors);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $errors
        ], 422);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'success'
    ], 200);
}
```

So, if code 200 is returned user is in the step2form:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" id="step2form" action="">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <!-- fields of the step 2-->
         <input type="submit" href="#step3" id="goToStep3" class="btn next-step" value="Go to step 3"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

step2 image to explain better:

[image]

When the user clicks in "Go to step 3" button is made an ajax request to validate the data and if there are no errors, code 200 is returned and the user go to the step 3, ajax request:

```
$("#credit_card_section").hide();
$("#references_section").hide();

var page_form_id_step2 = "step2form";

    $('#goToStep3').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id_step2);
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '{{ route('conferences.storePaymentMethods', compact('id','slug') ) }}',
            data: custom_form.serialize(),
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var result = data;
                if(result['payment_method'] == 'credit_card'){
                    $("#credit_card_section").show();
                    $("#references_section").hide();
                }else{
                    $("#references_section").show();
                    $("#credit_card_section").hide();
                }
                var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
                nextTab($active);
            },
            error: function (data) {
               // show errors
            }
        });
    });
```

The ConferenceController has the storePayment() to handle the ajax request above, it validates if the user selected a payment method and if yes returns code `200`:

```
public function storePaymentMethods(Request $request){
       $request->validate([
            'payment_method' => 'required',
        ]);
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success',
            'payment_method' => $request->payment_method,
        ], 200);
    }
```

Then there is the step3 div. In the step3 div it will appear the div `#credit_card_section` visible or `#references_section` visible depending on the payment method selected in the previous step (*credit card or references*):

```
<div>
    <form method="post" id="step3form" action="">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div id="credit_card_section">
                <!-- present necessary fields to
                payments with credit card-->
            </div>
              <div id="references_section">
        <!-- present generated reference to the user so he can pay-->
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

`step3` image to explain better, depending on the payment method the info that is necessary to show in step 3 is different. If the payment method was credit card also appears a `step4` div showing a success message after a successful charge with a credit card:

[image]

Then there is the step 4 div that should show the success message, after a completed payment with a credit card:

```
<div id="step4">
   <p>
   <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   Payment and registration completed with  success.
   </p>
</div>
```

// Resume of the methods of the RegistrationController that I have for now, the RegistrationController is the controller that I have that handles the multistep form

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public :function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
        // method that stores in session the ticket types 
       // selected by the user in the conference details page
        Session::put('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes);
        Session::put('allParticipants' , $allParticipants);
        Session::put('customQuestions' ,  $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions']);

        // and then redirects the user to the registartion page registration.blade.php 
        // using the route 'conferences.registration
        // this route is associated with the displayRegistrationPage() method
        return redirect(route('conferences.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }


  // method of the route 'conferences.registration' that displays
 //  the registration.blade.php that is the page with the multi step form
    public function displayRegistrationPage(Request $request, $id, $slug=null){
        // get the session values
        $selectedRtypes =  Session::get('selectedRtypes');
        $allParticipants = Session::get('allParticipants');
        $customQuestions = Session::get('customQuestions');

   // redirect the user to the registration.blade.php
        if(isset($selectedRtypes)) {
            return view('conferences.registration',
                ['selectedRtypes' => $selectedRtypes, 'customQuestions' => $customQuestions, 'id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]);
        }
        else{
            // return user to the conference details page
            return redirect(route('conferences.show',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
        }
    }

   /* the following methods are to handle the registration
      multi step  form of the registration.blade.php view */

   // method to handle the step1 of the multi step form
    public function storeRegistrationInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){

        // get and validate the fields of the step1 
       // and returns code 200 if al is ok

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);
    }


   // method to handle the step2 of the multi step form
    public function storePaymentMethods(Request $request){

        // validate if the payment_method field was filled
        // if was filled return code 200 
        // and returns the payment_method 
        //so in the step 3 div is possible to show a section for
       // when the payment_method is credit card (#credit_card_section) 
          or transfers ("transfers_section")
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success',
            'payment_method' => $request->payment_method,
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

Route for `step1`:

```
Route::post('/conference/{id}/{slug?}/registration/storeRegistrationInfo', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@storeRegistrationInfo',
    'as'   =>'conferences.storeRegistrationInfo'
]);
```

Route for `step2`:

```
Route::post('/conference/{id}/{slug?}/registration/storePaymentMethods', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@storePaymentMethods',
    'as'   =>'conferences.storePaymentMethods'
]);
```

Comment: Couldn't use session for storing values?

Comment: Sessions are not entirely reliable. I think you are on the right track. I think you are just confusing yourself trying to separate the logic for each little form. If it is not imperative to have them separated, I would make steps 1 2 and 3 be handled by a single controller like you did in `storePaymentMethods()` That is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in your doubts, to better structure your code and separate logic (DRY concept), you should do few things:

- Create `PaymentsController` with 3 functions (for the start, you will definitely add more here)

  1. for processing your references
  2. for processing credit cards
  3. for storing payment methods (store payment method in session, until user completes step3)

  You are totally free, on how you name these functions, but I would suggest something like `processViaReferences`, `processViaCreditCard` and `storePaymentMethod`.

  It will be much easier to read and validate, if you have them separated.

  Create corresponding post routes for them and reference appropriately, in cour code.
- Create part views containing your forms only.

  Then include, these part views via `@include` to have it separated on view level. For your references in javascript/jQuery, remember to keep correct ids of them. You can extract javascript, to other view part views or separate js files also, if you have not done it already.

  Your view/form code should go to these part views...

Comment: Thanks, but so the RegistrationController stays responsible of store the quantities selected in the conference details page in the session and to handle the validation of step 1 in the registration page? And the storePaymentMethods() that validate the step2 in the registration page should be removed from the RegistrationController and go to the PaymentController? And then also the PaymentController handles also the step3 (payment)?

Comment: Also, why is necessary to have more functions? It seems that only is necessary to have that 3 functions, that is, a function to process payments with references and other to process payments with references. And also other if the storePaymentMethods() should be removed from the RegistrationController and added to the PaymentController.

Comment: And also in the step3, for the code to process the payment is necessary to get the total price of the registration, the total value depends on the selected ticket types by the user in the conference details page. When the user selects the tickets that he wants for the conference in the conference details page the code goes to the storeQuantities() of the RegistrationController. The storeQuantities() stores in the session the info about the selected ticket types with "Session::put('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes);".

Comment: When a payment is done besides introduce an entry in the payments table is also necessary to introduce in the registrations, participants table, and some other tables to actually store the registration info. This code to store in these tables should also be in the PaymentController?

Comment: If the user selects the payment method "references" in step2 before the step3 appears the code to generate the references needs to be executed so I'm not understanding how the flow with that PaymentController should be.

Comment: @johnW so many comments, stackoverloaded... :))) I'll try to answer in order of incoming...

Comment: First true, that's the idea. I believe you have your RegistrationController in the right namespace (for example Conferences, cause for example app registration should live somewhere else, and for sure you have done it already)

Comment: Second also true. I meant that you can add more functions to this PaymentController logic wise and I'm sure you will in soon future...

Comment: Step3 your price should be here already. Do this in one of your controllers earlier, immediately when your receive required data for this calculations, and store your price in session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171893/discussion-between-bart-and-johnw).

Comment: @johnW did you  proceed anyhow on this, with my recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

There are no clear instructions, you need to decide for yourself how to organize your code.

If you can not choose exactly where to place the PHP code responsible for payment, then I would place processing of both payments in PaymentsController.php

So it is obvious that after choosing the method of payment you need to form something like an order in the database.

1. In case of references they will have to be tied to this order.
2. In case of using credit cards, payment will be tied to this order.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a beginner, so I'm having some doubts in organizing this multistep form context. I only have one RegistrationController to handle the registration process. The step1 (user info) and step2 (select payment method) are already working, in both steps, the info is validated. Then depending on the payment method, it is credit card is necessary to run some code to charge the card with stripe, if is references is necessary to present to the user the generated references.

Comment: If is credit card the payment proceeds immediately and its inserted in the payments table the price, payment_method_id, registration_id and status (paid). And the user is redirected to step 4 to show a success message.

Comment: If is references the user needs to proceed the payment using the generated references. When the user pays the system receives a notification and should be inserted in the payments table the price, payment_method_id, registration_id and status (paid).

Comment: In your opinion is better in the RegistrationController to have only the functions to handle the step 1 and step2 and then create a PaymentController for the step3? But can you explain better how this PaymentController should be?

Comment: there must be a method for creating referents for payment.
it should have methods for processing bank cards (you need to study the documentation of the payment library that you use).
Usually after payment they send a request to the server that needs to be processed. It is at this point that the purchase is completed and you can mark the user as paid in the database.

Comment: I already study the documentation and already have the code to generate the references for the case of the references payment method. And also have the code to charge the credit card in the case of payments with credit card. My doubt is about the flow. I updated the question to explain better.